# Pycharm debugger throws Bad file descriptor error when using dask distributed

Tags: python, pycharm, dask, dask-distributed

I am using the most lightweight/simple `dask` multiprocessing which is the non-cluster local `Client`:

```
from distributed import Client
client = Client()
```

Even so: the first instance of invoking `dask.bag.compute()` results in the following:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 191.7141.48)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 383, in _on_run
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 383, in _on_run
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 383, in _on_run
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

The result is that you can more or less flip a coin on whether the program will proceed or error out with a communication exception.  Here is what happens when the flip comes up "tails":

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 191.7141.48)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 383, in _on_run
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Process ForkServerProcess-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 178, in __init__
    from .counter import Digest
ImportError: cannot import name 'Digest' from 'distributed.counter' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/counter.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/process.py", line 181, in _run
    target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 587, in _run
    worker = Worker(*worker_args, **worker_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 552, in __init__
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/node.py", line 76, in __init__
    io_loop=self.io_loop,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.digests = defaultdict(partial(Digest, loop=self.io_loop))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 179, in ignoring
    yield
SystemError: error return without exception set
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker process 20417 exited with status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_pydevd_frame_eval/pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_37_64.pyx", line 95, in _pydevd_frame_eval.pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_37_64.get_bytecode_while_frame_eval
KeyError: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/bokeh/__init__.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1758, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1752, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1147, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/git/huddl/python/hamspam/enron.py", line 205, in <module>
    client = Client()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 712, in __init__
    self.start(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 858, in start
    sync(self.loop, self._start, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 331, in sync
    six.reraise(*error[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 316, in f
    result[0] = yield future
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 729, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 736, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 928, in _start
    yield self.cluster
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 729, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 603, in _wrap_awaitable
    return (yield from awaitable.__await__())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 736, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 284, in _start
    yield [self._start_worker(**self.worker_kwargs) for i in range(n_workers)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 729, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 501, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 316, in _start_worker
    raise gen.TimeoutError("Worker failed to start")
tornado.util.TimeoutError: Worker failed to start
```

Any advice on this?

There will be even more issues/complications when trying to use a `LocalCluster` mode -but that will be saved for a different question.

Comment: This looks like a bug.  If it only happens within PyCharm then I recommend raising a bug report with them.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  do you think a bug should be raised on pycharm?